# Find three numbers with a given sum and product

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to write a Python program to find three numbers whose sum and product are given by the user? For example, 3 + 3 + 5 = 11 and 3 × 3 × 5 = 45, so if I give it 11 and 45, it should return `(3, 3, 5)`.

Comment: "*is there a way to do it.*" I'm sure there is!

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html : The solvers module in SymPy implements methods for solving equations.

Comment: but you need a third equation ? or not ?

Comment: what i think is u can't directly solve it without having a third equation . but we can just take the prime factors of the product and find the three numbers

Comment: i think we need to see it for every permutations of the possible answer from the product's factors. @pippo1980

Comment: are the sum and product integers or floats ?

Comment: @rajdeeppaul well done, looks like you solved it.  Better if you check permutations of only numbers that divide into n.

Comment: integers @pippo1980

Comment: Brute force is likely to work fine here. You can loop through `for x in range(1, user_inputted_sum)` and inside of that loop through `for y in range(1, user_inputted_sum - x)` and determine the last digit as `z = user_inputted_sum - x - y` and then test if that permutation is equal to the product. It's ham-fisted, but it will solve and is likely what your instructor is after.

Comment: Of course the simple answer is `print(f'1,1,{n}')` ;)

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @martineau this isn't a homework question . I study in highschool but they dont ask questions like that here. but the way I framed it seemed like it was a homework question. I actually was learning unreal and in there for c++ i had this game triple x in which I had to guess 3 numbers whose sum and product are given. I just wanted to know how it would go if it were the opposite.

Comment: @martineau sir I did make an honest attempt but it was so big that it wasn't letting me put it out there.

Comment: Sorry, while not completely impossible, I find that *very* hard to believe… Anyway, since this also sounds like a fairly basic algebraic problem to me, maybe you should ask on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (where you don't need to show your own work).

Comment: @martineau thank u sir will remember it from the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caveman approach (brute force with a miniscule amount of dynamic programming). MiTriPy's answer generalizes to n variables, although probably isn't more performant.

```
def solve(eqsum, eqprod):
    solution_count = 0
    for x in range(1, eqsum+1):
        for y in range(1, eqsum+1-x):
            for z in range(1, eqsum+1-x-y):
                if x+y+z == eqsum:
                    if x*y*z == eqprod:
                        print(f"x={x} y={y} z={z}")
                        solution_count += 1
    print(f"Found {solution_count} solutions.");

solve(eqsum=11, eqprod=45)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, really really thank u this question was on my mind for a few days i tried to solve it many times but still wasn't able to come up with a solution.

Comment: @Mike Clark Nice and very clean, I was having so much fun but you broke the party, haha. Wrote another function to sort and check if the numbers are the same in the lists so it returns just one instance of (3, 3, 5) (for example), but I won't post it since your solution is much better.

Comment: Thanks now I have a real word example of brute force approach !!!

Answer (score 3):

Made something fast and very clumsy:

```
import itertools
from numpy import prod

def find_subset_of_numbers(number, product):
    subset_of_numbers = [x for x in range(1, number + 1)]
    for x in range(1, number+1):
        subset_of_numbers.append(x)
    for x in range(1, number+1):
        subset_of_numbers.append(x)

    result = [seq for i in range(3, 0, -1)
      for seq in itertools.combinations(subset_of_numbers, i)
      if sum(seq) == number and len(seq) == 3 and prod(seq) == product]

    return result
```

This will not handle duplicates very well but you could add another check for that:

```
print(find_subset_of_numbers(11, 45))
output: [(3, 5, 3), (3, 5, 3), (3, 3, 5), (3, 3, 5), (3, 5, 3), (3, 3, 5), (5, 3, 3), (3, 5, 3), (3, 3, 5)]
```

Comment: `return set(result)` instead of `return result` to remove duplicate answers! : )

Comment: @MikeClark returning straight set(result) will output: ```{(3, 3, 5), (5, 3, 3), (3, 5, 3)}``` because of the ordering ? 
I came out with something like this on the spot: ```return set(tuple(sorted(y)) for y in result)```

Edit: but yeah this is probably the most inefficient code I've ever written :D

Comment: `set()` does not preserve ordering because the mathematical (and Python) definition of a "set" specifically states that two sets are equivalent as long as they contain identical members, regardless of member ordering. `set()` uses value hashing internally which gives rise to the seemingly random ordering of results. I wish there was an order-preserving set built into Python. Since Python 3.7, a `dict()` is guaranteed to preserve insertion order, and I miss this all the time when using `set()` to reduce a list to unique values.

Comment: itertools.combinations (and even better, itertools.permutations) are two of the easiest ways to write massively inefficient code in the least number of keyboard keystrokes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly efficient solution.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator
from math import sqrt


def solve(target_sum: int, target_prod: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, int, int]]:
    for x in range(1, target_sum):
        if target_prod % x:
            continue
        midpoint = (target_sum - x) / 2
        try:
            radius = sqrt(midpoint ** 2 - target_prod // x)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        y = midpoint + radius
        if y.is_integer():
            y = int(y)
            z = int(midpoint - radius)
            yield (x, y, z)
            yield (x, y, z)
```

It uses the fact that if *x* + *y* = 2*m* and *xy* = *p*, then {*x*, *y*} = {*m* ± √(*m*² − *p*)}.

Comment: sorry downvoted by mistake cant undo it

Comment: Shouldnt be y = p/x ??

Comment: @pippo1980 That would give the same answer (or it will now, anyway – I fixed an error).